# Silverstripe 3.1 page has_one belongs_many dataobject

Tags: silverstripe

I have a `class ProductPage extends Page` and a `class ProductSpecifications extends DataObject`. Can I create a `$has_one` relationship to the Dataobject and a `$belongs_to` back to the ProductPage? (I know it's easier just to keep all the data associated to the page but I would prefer the ProductSpecifications as a separate dataobject). If so how do I access the CMSfields of the Dataobject from the Page? Gridfield? Or something like

```
$fieldsToAdd = ProductSpecifications::create();
$fieldsToAdd->getCMSFields();
$fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Specifications', $fieldsToAdd);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're speaking of a 1:1 relation? Then the heading of the question is a bit misleading.

You can edit a has_one "inline" using the [has one edit module](http://addons.silverstripe.org/add-ons/simonwelsh/hasoneedit)

hope that helps, wmk

Comment: Yes a 1:1 relation.  Does the $belongs_to back to the ProductPage manage a relationship, or is this unnecessary?

Comment: 1:1 is $has_one on the one side and $belongs_to on the other side. This way you can come to your main ProductPage from the related Specifications DataObject. If you don't need that it might be unnecessary, but it's more correct / elegant if you leave it in.
Did you try out the HasOneEdit module?